# Cannot get scroll-snap to work full screen

Tags: css, scroll

I have a site I'm working on: http://astra.kevbrown.ca/index2.php and cannot get the scroll-snap to work. I have a series of 100vh boxes and I want to snap to each as we scroll, to provide a narrative style of viewing.

```css
body {
 margin:0px;
 max-width:100vw;
 scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.box { 
 width: 100%;
 height:100vh;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: top center;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Any help on this folks?